# Is there any way of searching users from a specific country?

Tags: discussion

I want to search users from Taiwan at wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but you can use the Stack Exchange API at http://stackapps.com to write a small application that tries to match the location field to something matching some form of Taiwan.

(Note that location is a completely free-form unvalidated field, so it could contain literally anything..)

Answer (score 3):

**Find Stack Overflow Users In Your City (with user-links)**

http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/s/302/find-stack-overflow-users-in-your-city-with-user-links

Comment: Thanks a lot! (Damn, there are only 3 StackOverflow users in Taiwan and one is no longer a member).

Comment: There can be many more. As mentioned by @Jeff - users can write anything (or nothing) to the Location field.